# fastcgi_finish_request() undefined?

Tags: php

I have nginx setup with php-fpm on my server and am attempting to use  fastcgi_finish_request() however I receive message: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function fastcgi_finish_request()?

Is there something extra that I need to install on the server before this function is available? I've been digging around trying to find a solution and apparently haven't found the right keyword combination yet, or am highly confused about something???

Comment: I'd guess fpm ≠ fcgi?

Comment: was this not installed when i installed php-fpm?

Comment: actually you only can use fcgi functions if you also use fcgi. It's a SAPI, not a module/extension (look it up).

Comment: use phpinfo() to be sure you're running php through FPM

Comment: Alright, it may have been useful for me to mention that I am running this script via the command prompt (cron job). It appears as if the function is working if I call it via the application and not the command line. Is there a command for executing the script as fastcgi vs calling php command?

Comment: It appears I may be lacking a solid understanding about what exactly is going on when nginx is communicating with php-fpm vs. simply running php via the CLI. I'm researching now and will post back with my conclusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason I was receiving the "PHP Fatal Error" message was because I was calling the fastcgi_finish_request() method from a script that was not being executing through fastcgi. After researching this I now have a better understanding of php-fpm...so that's a plus :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it showed up when I looked for
`"Call to undefined function fastcgi_finish_request"`.
That's why I add what I found out here.

This script throws the error:

```
<?php
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo 'hello: ' . $now;
ignore_user_abort(true);
session_write_close();
fastcgi_finish_request();

sleep(10);
file_put_contents('test'.time().'txt', 'hello again: ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

But this does not:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain', true);
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo 'hello: ' . $now;
ignore_user_abort(true);
session_write_close();
fastcgi_finish_request();

sleep(10);
file_put_contents('test'.time().'txt', 'hello again: ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

So for some reason my PHP 7.4 FPM through Apache wants a header (example: `header('Content-type: text/plain', true);`) to be sent first...

Explanations are welcome!